# Jquery Is this the correct way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (SOMECONDITION) {
            $("#scriptD").attr("src", "../../Scripts/A.js");
        } else {
            $("#scriptD").attr("src", "../../Scripts/B.js");
        }

</script>

<script id="scriptD" src="" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am trying to insert a `.js` file dynamically ( on the condition basis). But this is not working . Can anybody tell me whats the problem here?

Comment: What does your error console show you?

Comment: Perhaps you should append the whole `#scriptD` tag to your `head`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do what you are trying is using [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
if (SOMECONDITION) {
    $.getScript("a.js");
} else {
    $.getScritp("b.js");
}
```

And besides, you way will work, if you place the script after the `<script>` element

```
<script id="scriptD" src="" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (SOMECONDITION) {
        $("#scriptD").attr("src", "../../Scripts/A.js");
    } else {
        $("#scriptD").attr("src", "../../Scripts/B.js");
    }

</script>
```

This is because the script will not be able to find `scriptD` on the DOM, when it is called before an element.

Comment: Shorter ;) `SOMECONDITION ? $.getScript("a.js") : $.getScript("b.js");`

Comment: @yaponyal, Absolutely, even shorter would be `$.getScript((SOMECONDITION) ? 'a.js' : 'b.js');` (UNTESTED) he he

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for getScript(url):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're parsing and executing the script before the `<script id='scriptD'>` exists in the DOM.  Either execute the function on `$(document).ready()` or rearrange it so the script tag is there before execution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        if (SOMECONDITION) {
            $("#scriptD").attr("src", "../../Scripts/A.js");
        } else {
            $("#scriptD").attr("src", "../../Scripts/B.js");
        }
      });

</script>
<script id="scriptD" src="" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="scriptD" src=""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        if (SOMECONDITION) {
            $("#scriptD").attr("src", "../../Scripts/A.js");
        } else {
            $("#scriptD").attr("src", "../../Scripts/B.js");
        }
    })();
</script>
```

The script you want to change the src MUST EXIST BEFORE making any changes to its attributes.
Or you might want to try this way - without the empty src script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script.setAttribute("src", "../../Scripts/" + (SOMECONDITION ? "A" : "B") + ".js");

        document.getElementByTagName(head)[0].appendChild(script);
    })();
</script>
```